# Capture keypress in Javascript (Google Docs)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, google-docs, bookmarklet

I'm trying to write a little greasemonkey script/bookmarklet/what have you for Google Docs. The functionality I'd like to add needs a keypress/keyup/keydown event handler (one of those three). Unfortunately, Javascript isn't my forté, and I can't seem to capture (?) a keypress event to while in the edit pane. As a last resort, I've tried the following:

```
javascript:(function(){
  els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for(i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    els[i].onkeypress=function(){alert("hello!");};
    els[i].onkeyup=function(){alert("hello2!");};
    els[i].onkeydown=function(){alert("hello3!");};
  }
})();
```

However, this still doesn't capture keypresses in the editing pane  - no annoying alerts (although it seems to work for most other sites...). I've checked in Chrome and Firefox both (I can't get it to work in either one).

I tried "Log Events" in Firebug (and checked out all the registered events via a neat little extension to Firebug, Eventbug); it didn't seem like those events were firing on keypresses.

Edit:
To clarify [Tim], I made this [screenshot](http://cl.ly/07413k1F3R3X1G0b3n0Y) with some annotations...
[image: screenshot]

The "editing pane" I'm talking about seems to be a bunch of Javascripted-up divs displaying what I type.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "editing pane"? Is it an iframe? A textarea?

Comment: @Jacob please check your profile email account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editing in Google Docs uses an iframe. You need to attach a listener to the iframe's document. It seems to do something complicated with the iframe I haven't yet been able to work out fully, but the following seems to work for Firefox:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
if (iframe) {
    iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
        console.log("iframe keypress: " + evt.which);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that and it indeed does exactly what I wanted - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me... but I'm using jQuery $(document).ready() to make sure my page is loaded before attaching any event.
I think you could do it in bare javascript with :

```
window.onload = function()
{
  els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for(i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
    els[i].onkeypress=function(){alert("hello!");};
  }
}
```

By the way you can't attach more than one function to the event:

```
for(i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    els[i].onkeypress=function(){alert("hello!");};
    els[i].onkeypress=function(){alert("hello2!");};
    els[i].onkeypress=function(){alert("hello3!");};
}
```

The element will register only the last one (it overrides the previous function), in this case "alert("hello3!");"

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo (I'll fix it above), thanks! I tried all three of "onkeypress", "onkeyup" and "onkeydown" to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to attach the listener to all the elements on the page. To attach it to the document is enough.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function() { alert("hello!"); });
}
```

Since it is a GreaseMonkey script you do not need to worry about IE and can use the `addEventListener` method.

Comment: Yep, that's what I tried first...My problem seems specific to Google Docs. The above code works fine on any other site, just not on Google Docs when editing a document. Does this work for you in that case?

Comment: I would think that they stop event for the further execution of their event handler. I was not able to get it work myself. I would think you need to remove their event listener and calling it manually. You could try taking a look at the closure js library that they use.