# Google docs: dispatch a keyboard event with userscript (tampermonkey)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, keyboard-events, userscripts, tampermonkey

I would like to simulate a keyboard event on a Google Docs to change the zoom.

I enter the div with the id `zoomSelect` with a mouse event:

```
var button = document.getElementById("zoomSelect");
triggerMouseEvent (button, "mouseover");
triggerMouseEvent (button, "mousedown");
triggerMouseEvent (button, "mouseup");


function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var eventObj        = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    eventObj.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent   (eventObj);
}
```

Then I would like to send a digit (let say 9). I tried all this options, but they don't work. The input doesn't receive the keypress. I also tried to dispatch the event directly to  `document` (instead of `button`), but it didn't work.

With KeyboardEvent:

```
var eventObj = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
(eventObj.initKeyEvent || eventObj.initKeyboardEvent)("keypress", true, true, null,
               0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, character.charCodeAt(9));

button.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
```

With event (without s):

```
var eventObj = document.createEvent('Event');
eventObj.initEvent('keydown', true, true);
eventObj.keyCode = 105;
button.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
```

With Events:

```
var eventObj = document.createEvent("Events");
(eventObj.initKeyEvent || eventObj.initKeyboardEvent)("keypress", true, true);

eventObj.keyCode = 105;
eventObj.which = 105;
eventObj.ctrlKey = false;
eventObj.shiftKey = false;
eventObj.altKey = false;
button.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
```

With new KeyboardEvent:

```
button.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {keyCode: 9}));
```

With dispatchKeyEvent:

```
button.dispatchKeyEvent("9");
```

The full [script](https://pastebin.com/i70ukC5W)

Comment: You can try the implementation from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4388829/6577242) which is to attach event listeners to the iframe.

Comment: I don't have a trouble with the event listener (I am able to use keyboard to trigger the MouseEvents). I only have trouble with dispatching a Key Event (sending a number like 115 to an input field on google docs)

Answer (score 0):

Your - With event (without s) will work with keypress event:

```
var eventObj = document.createEvent('Event');
eventObj.initEvent('keypress', true, true);
eventObj.keyCode = 105;
button.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
```

You will see a character "i" is inserted in the document at cursor location.
And a SAVE API is called.

Comment: Thanks for your help Prateek Jain, but  it doesn't work (I am using a tampermonkey userscript). The zoom text input is select (if I press some key on my keyboard they appear in the zoom text input) but the key from the script is never sent. Also I search for "save api" but I still dont' understand what you mean by that.